# C : sprintf inside printf as first argument

Tags: c, printf

Learning C at University. This is not a homework, but I was trying to do something (some "creative" part of the assignment) and got stuck.

I understand that this is possible

```
printf("%d\n", printf("23.4")); // -> 23.44 (i.e. 23.4 + 4 bytes written)
```

but how can I use `sprintf()` as first argument of `printf()` ?

something like :

```
char * getFormatString(int n) {
   char * buffer;

   sprintf(buffer, "Value with %%d decimals is %%.%df", n);

   return buffer; 
}

void foo() {
   int decimals = 2;
   float pi = 3.141592;

   printf(getFormatString(decimals), decimals, pi);  // should output "Value with 2 decimals is 3.14"
}
```

Is this even possible ? So far, I get a seg fault when executing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sprintf` for this purpose is perverse. Instead try:

```
printf("Value with %d decimals is %.*f", decimals, decimals, pi);
```

Comment: excellent! You have my respect and I stand corrected :) I never heard about that behavior (reading http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should at least allocate memory for your buffer first (and free it at the end):

```
char * buffer;
int decimals = 2;
float pi = 3.141592;

buffer = (char *) malloc(256); /* big enough buffer */
sprintf(buffer, "Value with %%d decimals is %%.%df", decimals);
printf(buffer, decimals, pi);

free(buffer);
```

Comment: alright, I understand. But if sprintf() and printf() are located in different functions ? One function returns a char * for the first argument of the printf function?

Comment: @Yanick `sprintf()` returns an int.

Comment: @Yanick I think you're using the word "returns" wrong.  printf/sprintf both *return* ints.  But they *take* char* as their first argument.

Comment: I'll edit the question to clarify (I do understand what the functions return, but I think there's a misunderstanding nevertheless)

Comment: If you're going to use a fixed-size buffer, there's no need for `malloc`; you can use `char buf[256]` (unless you're concerned about stack usage).  One always should use `snprintf` over `sprintf` anyway, though.

Answer (score 2):

[printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) returns the number of characters printed, so your first example would actually be

```
printf("%d", printf("23.4")); // -> 23.44
```

sprintf also returns the number of characters printed, so having it be an argument of printf probably isn't what you want.

The reason you're seg-faulting is that your buffer string isn't pointing to anything.  You want to change your code to something like this:

```
char buffer[1024];    // buffer has to be an actual string (or you could use malloc)
int decimals = 2;
float pi = 3.141592;

sprintf(buffer, "Value with %%d decimals is %%.%df", decimals);

printf(buffer, decimals, pi);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a segfault, because `sprintf` writes data to some place in memory which is pointed to by garbage (in the pointer `buffer`). You need to allocate some memory using malloc, like:

```
buffer = malloc(100);
```

before you use sprintf in function `getFormatString`. Then, remember to free this memory after using your string. In this particular code there is a memory leak, because you don't store the pointer returned from `getFormatString` anywhere.

Corrected code:

```
char *getFormatString(int n) {
    char *buffer = malloc(100);
    sprintf(buffer, "Value with %%d decimals is %%.%df", n);
    return buffer;
}

void foo() {
    int decimals = 2;
    float pi = 3.141592;
    char *fmtstr = getFormatString(decimals);
    printf(fmtstr, decimals, pi);  // should output "Value with 2 decimals is 3.14"
    free(fmtstr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` and `sprintf()` both return an `int` value. Which is the total number of characters.

```
int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

You can only use `sprintf()` as an argument to `printf()` if you are to print the number of characters written by `sprintf()`.